# Xamarin: Phone number verify

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project. I want to add a functionality where the user has to provide his phone number **only when he/she first open the application.**

Then the app has to send a push notification to that mobile number with a verification code. And user has to provide that number in the application.

I am new to Xamarin forms, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You could use Firebase Authentication to sign in a user by sending an SMS message to the user's phone. The user signs in using a one-time code contained in the SMS message. Check the link:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: I checked that. The tutorial is in java right. Can I please know how to do it with c# (for Xamarin forms)

Comment: @NSR Check this [tutorial](https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/) of firebase authentification for Xamarin Forms

Comment: With app center auth you can send push to users  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/auth/